# What Programming Language is this? I want to pass parameters to this Datastage Job. How to do it?

Tags: job-scheduling, ca, datastage

I am a Java developer and I suddenly had to move to a Datastage Support role for a short time. I need to run batch Jobs and need to modify few scripts. Can anyone tell me what language is this?

```
FILE_TRIGGER trigger.name
AGENT aname
RESOURCE ADD (-----)
FILENAME + path
USER uname
RELEASE (Jobname)
ENDJOB

LINUX_JOB jobname
SCRIPTNAME /SI...
ARGS Group ....
USER uname
AGENT aname
ENDJOB
```

The above script is used to trigger datastage jobs. I have tried to find resources in the Internet but all I could find is related to ESP workload Manager and Job schedulers. What would be the resources for this language. How to pass parameters for a Job? Any resources would be really helpful.

Comment: There are no coworkers that can explain your new task to you?

Comment: No, there are none, The only one left the job with very little, Go here, Go there and do this kind of knowledge transfer. I am looking for resources so that I can learn and not expecting any solutions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Looks like a "job scheduler" syntax. It looks vaguely similar to Ca-Scheduler (I used it 30 years ago). Searching on File_Trigger gives: https://communities.ca.com/thread/100484358. I would suggest it is Computer Associates Job scheduler, Not sure what they call it now

Comment: Thank you, I will try to find more resources on this.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is ESP PROC of [CA Workload Automation ESP Edition](http://www.ca.com/us/products/ca-workload-automation-esp-edition.html)

Resources:

- [User Guide for syntax](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Workload%20Automation%20CA%207%20Edition%20-%20Public%2011%203-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/PDF/IAS_User_ENU.pdf)
- [CA Workload Automation Communites](https://communities.ca.com/community/ca-workload-automation)

To pass parameters to job use ARGS statement:

```
LINUX_JOB testDataStage
SCRIPTNAME /<DS_HOME>/bin/dsjob -server xxx -user xxxx -password xxxx -run...
ARGS "first parameter" "second" "third"
USER xxxxx
AGENT xxxx
ENDJOB
```